# Facebook GET /v2.6/{friend-list-id}/members Return Blank in API v2.6

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.6

FB.login(function(response) {

```
 console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
  FB.api(
    "/me/friendlists",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {          
          $.each(response.data, function (key,value) {           
               //console.log(value.id);        
                 FB.api(
                    "/"+value.id+"/members",
                    function (response) {
                      if (response && !response.error) {

                          console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
                        /* handle the result */
                      }
                    }
                );            
          });    
          console.log(JSON.stringify(response));
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```

I am Using this code to get friendlist in facebook latest API. 
That return blank array in return. I got all my FriendList Id. But after call /members that return blank.

I am testing with "Test application and use 'read_custom_friendlists' permission"

Comment: I assume they would just return app friends just like /me/friends

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to get a list of friends? You can only get friends who authorized your App with the `user_friends` permission, and this would be the API call: `/me/friends`.

More information: [Facebook Graph Api v2.0+ - /me/friends returns empty, or only friends who also use my app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23417356/facebook-graph-api-v2-0-me-friends-returns-empty-or-only-friends-who-also-u)

Comment: I want full friendlist.

Comment: take a look at the link in my answer. you can´t get the full friendlist anymore. only for inviting or tagging users.

Comment: I want big profile pic of user so i can not go with  inviting or tagging users :(

Comment: that´s not possible then. stick with users who authorized your app too.